# How to see what is in a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I would like to see which files are in my jar File.
I've found out that I need to use `java -jar`
 on my CentOS VM. But how do I add the parameters `tf`.

At the end I have something like: `java -jar "MyJarFile.jar" -tf`.

When I do it like that the parameters are getting ignored..

Comment: Do you mean de-compile the jar?

Comment: Just unzip the JAR.

Comment: Use [Java Decompiler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler).

Comment: There is a tool called **jar** that takes -jf. java -jar **runs** a jar file. You cant give options such as tf to it!

Comment: Use 7zip, WinZip or such; rename it to a .zip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use decompression software (.jar is just an archive).